# XAMPP MYSQL start and stop after 3 seconds

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know what's this error log mean ? please help me fix my mysql

```
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.14 started; log sequence number 839185; transaction id 1714
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-01-09 14:04:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210109 14:04:02
```

i'd been searching for every solution but every solutions refer to delete everything in here

```
c:\xampp\mysql\data\
```

but i don't want because i'll lose all of the database

i'm using this mysql with laravel migrations

Comment: None of these are errors, these are comp,etely normal log entries rekating to a successful start of a mysql instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Xampp>mysql>backup. Simply copy all the files of backup folder then goto
Xampp>mysql>data folder path. Simply Select all files by pressing Ctrl+A then paste (press Ctrl+V).

By this process it replace mendatory files of MySQL Service.

Comment: maybe that's work if i backup the ibdata1 file from the old one as mentioned in here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653647/xampp-mysql-start-and-stop-after-3-seconds/65653780#65653780

in the end i lost everything and started new :( anyways it works.. thank you